# Robots.txt for Magento 2.1+ - where did it go?

Tags: magento2, seo, robots.txt

Where is the actual robots.txt file like Magento 1.9.x if it exists?

> My site URL /robots.txt does not work.

The official dev docs for this http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/search-engine-robots.html have an image with a note below it stating

> This will be included in before head closing tag in page HTML.

When I inspect the homepage in the  tag of the HTML I do not see a reference to the robots.txt or any directives like "INDEX, NOINDEX, FOLLOW, NOFOLLOW".  I was searching for more information on this, and think others here probably have as well.

Can someone explain how **robots.txt** functions in Magento2?

Comment: robots.txt is just a file.configure it. click save. and forget.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your **robots.txt** in the folder `pub/robots.txt`, I recommend you remove it and generate using the admin panel, via the route below you can choose the second option listed and change the SEO **robots.txt**.

> Content > Design > Configuration

Answer (score 0):

[This excellent guide explains this in detail.](https://inchoo.net/online-marketing/editing-robots-txt-in-magento-2-admin/) In M2, a separate module called module-robots is responsible for routing and rendering the robots file.